# Power BI Blank Drillthrough Results

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a single table in Power BI. There are no other tables being used, everything is in 1 table.

When I drill down, I don't get any results to come back despite having numbers in my Matrix Visual.

Any idea why this might be?

Answer (score 0):

Select one of the visuals where the drill through is working.
On the list of filters off to the right, put whatever column(s) your visual is using as a filter.

This should solve everything.